# How can I implement using Apple SF Symbols in a Xamarin Forms app targeting iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a SwiftUI application that uses the car.fill from Apple SF Symbols in a view like this:

```
Image(systemName: "car.fill")
  .resizable()
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
  .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
```

Now I am creating a similar application using Microsoft Xamarin Forms targeting iOS, and have been unsuccessful in discovering how to do same. Can anyone help?

Comment: For better compatibility with iOS versions bellow 13, I export them ... and bring them into assets as pngs -  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

Comment: @TonyMkenu I did see that I could use SVG files in my shared project and then reference in the XAML using the Xamarin.Forms.Svg Nuget pkg. I was hoping that the SF Symobols would be as easy to use as they are in SwiftUI.

Comment: don't complicate yourself with SVG ... convert files to png

Comment: To me using PNG's is more complicated. Requires all the different sizes named appropriately and put into proper locations within both Droid and iOS projects. Not sure why SVG is not the standard.

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT

Answer (score 2):

The **[SF Symbols](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios-13-and-xcode-11/#sfsymbols)** are already included in **XCode 11+** and **iOS 13**. In Xamarin.iOS, we could choose them directly in the storyboard(the effect only works for **Visual Studio For Mac**).

[image]

If using code (the effect both works for **VS for Pc** and **VS for Mac**), we could implement it using code behind like:

```
MyImage.Image = UIImage.GetSystemImage("car.fill");
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this on the Xamarin iOS release announcement from 2019. But I don't use storyboards. How would I do this in my shared project in Xamarin Forms XAML ? For example to use Font Awesome I can simply do this in XAML. <Button Text="&#xf040;" FontFamily="FontAwesome" />

Comment: Okey, you could have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4). In addition, if not mind using `Xaml` to set font aswsome, you also could use code to set by using navtive method of custom `ImageRenderer`.